# what should be the RegExp for app version validation?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am stuck in one RegExp where I need to validate app version for app store and play-store. I have tried several RegExp but none of them is useful for me. Here are the example that pass the test

App version up-to 2-3 decimal point

```
1.0 // pass

1.0.0 // pass

1.0.0.0 // fail

a.0 // fail

1 // pass
```

I found one RegExp `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` but this will only be valid when I have enter 4 decimal points. I don't know how to modify this.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have mentioned `up to 2-3 decimal` then the `RegExp` must be this

```
^(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following regex

```js
let reg = /^[0-9]((\.)[0-9]){0,2}$/

console.log(reg.test('1.0')) //true
console.log(reg.test('1.1.0')) //true
console.log(reg.test('1')) //true

console.log(reg.test('1.')) //false
console.log(reg.test('1.a')) //false
console.log(reg.test('1.1.1.1')) //false
```

Comment: You forgot to escape the `.`. So things like `1°1` and `1M1` will also pass the test...

Answer (score 4):

`^\d+(?:\.\d+){0,2}$`

This will start with a number (`\d` is the same as `[0-9]`) and then zero or more decimal point followed by more numbers.

```js
var input = [
  "1.0", // pass
  "1.0.0", // pass
  "1.0.0.0", // fail
  "a.0", // fail
  "1", // pass
  "1.",
  "1.a"
]

var regex = /^\d+(?:\.\d+){0,2}$/;

input.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item, regex.test(item));
});
```

If you want to limit the number of digits, you can change the `\d+` into `\d{n,m}` (replace `n` with the minimum number of digits and `m` with the maximum number of digits).

The `+` is the same as `{1,}` which means "one or more".

Comment: According to OP: `1.0.0.0 // fail` but your code is returning `true`

Comment: @MaheerAli OP change question rquirements - in  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55156090/1) version this example pass.

Comment: @MaheerAli The OP changed the requirements after I answered the question. I updated it now.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
^(\d+\.){0,2}\d+$
```

```js
let versions= [
  "1.0",
  "1.0.0",
  "1.0.0.0",
  "a.0",
  "1",
]

versions.forEach(v=> console.log(v, /^(\d+\.){0,2}\d+$/.test(v) ) );
```

Comment: This will accept things like `1.` and `1.a` - It's unclear from the question if it's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one useful for my case

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d+){2}$/gm
```

This will match only the versions made of 3 dots and numbers only

Example:

1.2.3 - matches

21.5.3 - matches

1.2.3.4 - fails

1.a.4 - fails